# Call to a member function is_loggedin() on null

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to check if the user is logged in by calling the is_loggedin() function, so I can show the logout button and hide the login button and I keep getting this error, Call to a member function is_loggedin() on null any help would be mostly appreciated. when I do var_dump($user) it returns null.

Navigation page

```
<?php
$user = new USER();
?>
<?php 
if (!$user->is_loggedin()) { 
?>    
  <li><a class="hide-for-medium-only" href="login_form.php">Login</a></li>
<?php 
} else { 
?>
  <li><a class="hide-for-medium-only" href="login_form.php">Logout</a></li>   
<?php
} 
?>
```

login function

```
public function is_loggedin()
{
  if (isset($_SESSION['user_session'])) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your `is_loggedin` function a method of the class `$user` is an instance of?

Comment: @wogsland: `call to ... on null`. that means $user is `null`, not an object.

Comment: yeah its a method in my $user class

Comment: $user has, probably, no value or is not of the object type that you expected. with if ($user == null) you could test whether it is null or do var_dump($user) to see what is in the $user variable.

Comment: `$user` is null, you need to make sure what it is by doing `var_dump($user)` at the top of your script.

Comment: do i put var_dump($user) in my user class

Comment: So, where does this `$user` var come from?

Comment: I am calling my class ill on the navigation page ill edit my code to show you what I mean.